# How to get model predictions with the svyolr function

Tags: r, survey

I'm using the `svyolr` function from the `survey` package to run an ordinal regression model. I'd like to analyze the model by inspecting the predictions it would make for my survey data and for hypothetical sets of data.

Since there doesn't seem to be a `predict` method for the `svyolr` function, how can I get model predictions from a fitted `svyolr` model?

Here's some example data and a simple example model to work with:

```
library(survey)

# Load example data
data(api)

# Create a survey design object
dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

# Add an ordinal variable to the data
dclus1 <- update(dclus1, mealcat=cut(meals,c(0,25,50,75,100)))

# Fit an ordinal regression model
m <- svyolr(formula = mealcat ~ avg.ed + stype,
            design = dclus1)

# Generate fake data to use in evaluating model predictions
fake_data <- dclus1$variables[,c("avg.ed", "stype")]
fake_data <- subset(fake_data, !is.na(avg.ed))
```

Answer (score 1):

svyolr is based on MASS::polr so i guess you could hack a prediction algorithm for that..

i doubt the confidence intervals that glm.predict::polr.predict() generates are legitimate

```
library(glm.predict)
library(survey)


data = MASS::survey
data$Smoke = ordered(MASS::survey$Smoke,levels=c("Never","Occas","Regul","Heavy"))
model1 = MASS::polr(Smoke ~ Sex + Height, data=data)
summary(model1)
# comparing a man to a woman
polr.predict(model1, c(1,170),sim.count=10000)


this_design <- svydesign( ~ 1 , data = data , weights = ~ Age )
model2 = svyolr(Smoke ~ Sex + Height, this_design)
class(model2) <- 'polr'

# prediction for male with height 170
( this_prediction <- polr.predict(model2, c(1,170),sim.count=10000) )


fake_data <- data[ c( 'Sex' , 'Height' ) ]
fake_data <- fake_data[ complete.cases( fake_data ) , ]
fake_data[ , ] <- sapply( fake_data[ , ] , as.numeric )

# lowering sim.count just so it runs faster
res <- apply( fake_data , 1 , function( w ) polr.predict(model2, w ,sim.count=100) )

# prediction for the first record
res[1:4,1]
# lower CI for the first record
res[5:8,1]
# upper CI for the first record
res[9:12,1]

# prediction of heavy smoking for every record
fake_data[ , 'predicted_heavy_smoking' ] <- res[ 4 , ]
```

Comment: Yes, in the News.md file for the package, Dr. Lumley says that for `svyolr`, "code [was] ripped from MASS package." This is very helpful. Could you explain the concern you raised about the confidence intervals from `glm.predict` or mention a resource for further reading?

Comment: hi, the confidence interval estimates are based on 100 or 1,000 or 10,000 simulations but not on any adjustment due to the sampling uncertainty.  `MASS::polr` expects data from a simple random sample.  this hack will give you confidence intervals that are too small..so you do have a best guess but you don't really know how good the guess is

Comment: Thank you, Anthony. It seems then that review of the relevant survey statistics literature would be necessary before trying to adapt code from MASS::polr().